# How to sort characters after a period

Tags: sorting

Need help on how to sort characters or numbers after a period(.)

```
test2.rod1
test1.rod1
test3.rod1
test1.mor2
test2.mor2
test3.mor2
zbcd1.abc1
abcd2.abc1
dbcd3.abc1
```

I would like the sort result anything after the period (.). Result should be something like below.

```
abcd2.abc1
dbcd3.abc1
zbcd1.abc1
test1.mor2
test2.mor2
test3.mor2
test2.rod1
test1.rod1
test3.rod1
```

Comment: Is there a particular language that you would like this done in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a system with Unix like utilities such as MacOS, Linux, BSD, etc, then you can use the system sort command.  The secret is to specify the field delimiter, which in your case is a period.  The argument is either -t or --field-separator.  So the following should work:

```
  sort -t. -k 2  test.dat
```

Assuming that your data is in a file called test.dat